# SAML 2.0 security token

Tags: authorization, saml

I have a web application which uses an identity provider for authentication in accordance with SAML 2.0 protocol.

Does this web application (service provider) have to validate a security token (provided by IdP when an user log in the web application) for each web server request.

In my opinion, there is no need to validate security token for each server request. The SAML protocol requires token validation only in necessary cases (authentication, authorization).

Am I right or od I have to implement token validation for each web server request?

Answer (score 0):

No, the service provider does not need to validate the SAML assertion for every request.

SAML assertion contains information about the user, such as who the username is, how the user is authenticated by identity provider, and so on. Once the service provider obtains this SAML assertion from identity provider, it verifies the SAML assertion, and log-ins the user to the service provider. Once the user is logged-in, the user only needs to use the same authenticated session to access protected resource at the service provider. The user does not have to send SAML assertion.

Comment: In addition, SAML Responses are by design "one time use only" for Web SSO. This means you need to ensure your SAML solution does not allow a replay of the same message to ensure you are compliant with the spec.